# Can you check available hard disk space with Adobe Air?

Tags: air, hard-drive

We have an Adobe Air app that downloads a large amount of images into application storage.  I've scanned the docs and found no sign of this, but I thought I'd double check: anyone know if it's possible to see how much available storage space the user has on their HD so we can warn them they don't have enough room?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer, it is possible:

```
air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.spaceAvailable
```

It was in the docs after all.  RTFM.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.1/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WSC2FAD3B6-D59A-4e4d-B63F-9846584CF5D5

Comment: If the above link didn't work, try http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#spaceAvailable